# Commit Worklight project on a CVS

Tags: cvs, ibm-mobilefirst

during the past months we were looking for the best way to share our worklight project.
I understood is useless to commit the native resources that the "Build all and deploy" creates, but i wish i could know how to correctly commit the environments besides the common folder.
We are using WL 5.0.6.1 and in the near future WL 6.0

Comment: I don't quite understand the question... aside of the native folder of a mobile environment, the environment folders are not different from the common folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I checked, there was an eclipse CVS bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=79869) that made it impossible to use CVS with Worklight projects.

The Worklight Infocenter has information on what/what not to check in:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html

I've used Rational Team Concert, Subversion and Git with worklight projects, all with success.

I have a (somewhat dated) blog post on using Subversion with Worklight here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_source_code_management_with_worklight_subversion?lang=en